# SharePoint Online - How to display the links of a summary link web part in a Horizontal Manner?

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, css, display-template, links

I am trying to display links of a Summary Link web part in horizontal pattern. I am not good in CSS to make these changes. Please let me know if there is another way to do it? If the only way is through changes in CSS, how to access style sheet for that SharePoint page?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your best best, if the OOTB **configuration styles and layout** settings don't fit your needs, is to create a custom css file. You can upload this css file into your **site assets** folder and then in the **sharepoint desinger** customize the master page by adding a reference to this css file.